# KMS / Office 2010... please point to documentation

Tags: kms, microsoft-office-2010

Trying to find out how to "modify" KMS to also accept the Office 2010 KMS key. Can anyone point me to some document about this?

Basically - do I have to install an update to KMS? I wand my KMS server to authenticate both, Windows (It currently has a DataCenter R2 KMS key installed) as well as Office 2010. Keys are available ;)

I can not imagine I just ptu it in - would this not overwrite the DataCenter key? I tried the MSDN website, but there is no clear document visible for my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self-answer:

I needed to download http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=97b7b710-6831-4ce5-9ff5-fdc21fe8d965&displayLang=en - the Office 2010 KMS Host License Pack.

This modifies KMS to also activate Office, as the stock KMS is not able to ;)